# Marshall monitor 2 ANC headset: swap bluetooth connection

Tags: audio, headphones

I just got a Marshall monitor 2 ANC headset, and unlike my previous headset (Senheizer HD 4.5), to switch the bluetooth connection to the laptop or tablet, i heave to unpair to wherever it's connected, and pair it again where i need it. Actually, when pressing + hold the golden knob, so the light blinks blue, and is detected in the new device; if it has a current connection, blinks a greenish / blue color, and is never detected in that new device.

And the Marshall app never detects in both cases

So the question would be: is this a misconfiguration of my system, or just the way this headset works?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s a question for Marshall customer service and is purely electronic rather than musical.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is it a device connectivity issue, unrelated to music theory or practise.